# Projection non-expansive in $\ell_2$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

It is well-known that for a convex closed set $K\subset\mathbb{R}^D$, the projection operator $\Pi:\mathbb{R}^D\rightarrow K$ given by
$$
\Pi(x)=\arg \min_{y\in K} \| x-y\|_2
$$
is non-expansive in the norm $\ell_2$, that is,
$$
\| \Pi(x) - \Pi(x')\|_2 \leq \| x - x'\|_2, \forall x,x'\in \mathbb{R}^D.
$$
But how to prove it?

I am a freshman in linear algebra, if the proof is obvious, please share me with the link. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=\Pi(x).$
Then $x$ and $K$ are located on the opposite sides of the hyperplane through $y$ and perpendicular to $x-y.$ Hence  for any $u\in K$ we have
$$\langle x-y,u-y\rangle \le 0$$
Similarly for $y'=\Pi(x')$ and any $v\in K$ there holds
$$ \langle x'-y',v-y'\rangle \le 0$$
In particular for $u=y'$ and $v=y$ we get
$$\langle x-y,y'-y\rangle \le 0,\quad \langle x'-y',y-y'\rangle \le 0$$ Adding up the inequalities gives
$$\langle (x-x')+(y'-y),y'-y\rangle \le 0$$
Hence
$$\|y'-y\|^2\le \langle x'-x,y'-y\rangle \le \|x'-x\|\,\|y'-y\|$$ Thus $\|y'-y\|\le \|x'-x\|.$